# Solve $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(t) \sin ^2 (t-\theta) dt = g(\theta)$ for unknown function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, convolution

Let $g(\theta)$ be a known real-valued function with domain $[0, 2\pi]$. Given that:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(t) \sin ^2 (t-\theta) dt = g(\theta)$$

How would I solve for the unknown real-valued function $f(t)$? Is the solution unique?

---

We can assume $f$ is integrable. The function $g$ is known, so its Fourier series and Fourier transform can be readily computed. But how to use them to find $f$?

Comment: Your question has no sense ! $f$ is an integrable function on $[0,2\pi]$ otherwise the question wouldn't have any sense. So, what is the question ?

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Convolution with $1-\cos (2t)$ can be written in a more transparent form in terms of the Fourier coefficients. If you can get the Fourier coefficients of $g$, that would help.

Comment: @Surb Sure, we can assume $f$ is integrable. I am asking how $f$ can be determined over $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @Woodface $g$ is known, so the Fourier series and Fourier transform can be readily computed. How would I use it to find $f$?

Comment: @science This question came up when I was trying to understand something in this paper: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/psd3/multi/remote/pdf/TGARS_2000b.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for the Fourier series of $f$: 
$$
f(t) = \frac{A_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(A_n\cos nt+B_n\sin nt) \tag{1}
$$
When this is multiplied by 
$$\sin^2(t-\theta ) = \frac12-\frac12\cos(2(t-\theta ))
= \frac12-\frac12\cos 2\theta \cos 2t - \frac12 \sin  2\theta  \sin 2t 
$$ and integrated over the circle, most terms cancel out due to orthogonality. You end up with 
$$
\frac12\left(\pi A_0 -  A_2\cos 2\theta -B_2\sin 2\theta\right)  \tag{2}
$$
And this is what you are equating to $g$... so there is no solution unless $g$ is of the form $(2)$. And if it happens to be of that form, there are infinitely many solutions because all coefficients in $(1)$ except $A_0,A_2,B_2$ can be anything.

Summary: the problem is that the kernel $\sin^2(t-\theta)$ has few harmonics. Something like the Gaussian kernel would allow you to solve the equation for a wide class of functions $g$.

Comment: I'm trying to determine if a solution exists if $g$ is $D \cos^2(\theta)+E \sin^2(\theta)$, where $D,E$ are non-negative real numbers and $D \neq E$. I was not successful in getting to match (2), so I posted another question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205444/trignometric-function-manipulation