# Comparing the sum of squared trigonometric functions and the sum of functions of double argument

Tags: trigonometry

Let $D,E$ be two non-negative real numbers such that $D \neq E$. Do there exist real numbers $A,B,C$ such that:

$$A \cos(2\theta)+B \sin(2\theta)+C = D \cos^2(\theta)+E \sin^2(\theta)?$$

I used $\cos(2\theta) = \cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)$, but it doesn't seem to help.

EDIT: What if there is a stronger requirement on $D,E$: $D,E$ are two **positive** real numbers and $D \neq E$?

Comment: you can turn this into $a\cos 2t + b \sin 2t = c.$ and this  has at most two solutions in $0 \le t \le \pi]$ answer is no if you are expecting an identity.

Comment: Yes, this work, but I just realized $D$ and $E$ must be both zero for that to work. What would happen under the stronger requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\cos2\theta = \cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=\color{Red}{2\cos^2\theta-1=1-2\sin^2\theta}$ $$\cos^2\theta=\dfrac{1+\cos2\theta }{2}$$
$$\sin^2\theta=\dfrac{1-\cos2\theta }{2}$$ Therefore
$$D\cos^2\theta+E\sin^2\theta=\left(\dfrac{D-E}{2}\right)\cos2\theta+\left(\dfrac{D+E}{2}\right)$$ Choose $$A=\left(\dfrac{D-E}{2}\right),\,\,\,\,\,\,B=0,\,\,\,\,\,C=\left(\dfrac{D+E}{2}\right).$$

Comment: How is it an answer?

Comment: Consider $$D \cos^2\theta+E \sin^2\theta.$$ You can find $A, B$ and $C$ in terms of $D,E.$

Comment: Thanks Nilan. What do you think about the stronger requirement?

Comment: For any $D,E$ these two identities are hold. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. There seems to be typo - the $cos^2$ might be $cos2\theta$ in the line after "Therefore".

Answer (score 2):

just a thought - if we write $x$ for $\cos \theta$ and $y$ for $\sin \theta$ then the equation may be written:
$$
A(x^2-y^2) + 2B xy + C (x^2+y^2) = Dx^2+Ey^2
$$
or
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta & \sin \theta \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} A+C-D & -B \\ -B & -A-E+C \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta \\ \sin \theta \end{pmatrix} = 0
$$

Comment: Interesting! Does this help us find solutions somehow?

Answer (score 2):

$A \cos(2\theta)+B \sin(2\theta)+C = D \cos^2(\theta)+E \sin^2(\theta)$

$ = (D+E)/2 + \cos (2\theta) (D-E)/2 $

Comparing coefficients of constants and variables we get simply

$$ A = (D-E)/2 , B =0, C = (D+E)/2. $$

I did not understand why at start you thought it cannot a simple direct identity.

Comment: I was not able to do it immediately so frankly I thought it cannot be done. I mean, there is no guarantee problems of this form (double angle trig functions on one side and squared trig functions on the other) always yield solutions, right? It's great this one has solutions.